# Evaluate gradient for each input keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I want to be able to access the gradient function of a keras neural network. I want to be able to compute the gradient of the output with respect to the input at many input values. Essentially I want to be able to evaluate the gradient as a function.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',  metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), epochs=2, verbose = 1)
```

Now instead of evaluating the output at every input, I want to evaluate the gradient at every input. How can I do this?

This is what I have tried.

```
grads = K.gradients(model.output, model.input)
gradient_func = K.function([model.input], [grads[0]])
print(gradient_func([x]))
```

Comment: write a custom loss function that includes gradient using keras backend operations.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: I want to be able to view the gradient at each input.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you already have? It seems to do what you need.

Comment: It is very slow and uses a lot of memory.